# Hoverable menu items

Tags: html, css

I have a menu with different items, these items are returned from a controller, and looks like this.

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.LoggedIn)
{
    if (item.Url == path)
     {
      <li><a class="active" href="@item.Url">@item.Text</a></li>

      }
      else
      {
       <li><a href="@item.Url">@item.Text</a></li>
      }
      <li class="slider"></li>
}
```

It is the "li" at the end, which is of class="slider" which is the "hover/slider" I somehow have to define the starting position of that slider.

The hovering is defined like this in the css.

```
.menu li:nth-child(1):hover ~ .slider,
.menu li:nth-child(1):focus ~ .slider,
.menu li:nth-child(1):active ~ .slider {
   left: 0;
   background-color: #3498db;
 }

.menu li:nth-child(2):hover ~ .slider,
.menu li:nth-child(2):focus ~ .slider,
.menu li:nth-child(2):active ~ .slider {
     left: 20%;
     background-color: #9b59b6;
 }
```

and so on.

The selected link is defined as active after the button is pushed. The problem is that the "hover/slider" starts at the left side.
This is illustrated in the picture below. In that example About is clicked, but the "hover/slider" starts at Home, which is kinda weird.

[image]

I would like to know how I could make the slider/hover (which is at Home in the image) to be where the link is active (About)

The generated HTML is provided below.

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="/Home/Index">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="active" href="/Home/About">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/Account/Register">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/Account/Login">Log in</a>
    </li>
    <li class="slider" id="menu_slider"></li>
</ul>
```

When implementing the slider in the answer I get the following error (the red line is not supposed to be covering the entire menu, just the selected link)

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: haha, I guess it disappeared in the text. I would like to know how I could make the slider/hover (which is at Home in the picture) to be where the link is active (About)

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: I have done it already.

Comment: Are you able to post the end result of your html?  Everything between the `<ul>` tags?

Comment: Updated the question with an image of it.

Comment: What do you mean when you say slider?  Are you using some sort of js plugin?

Comment: You should put your code in a snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I understand from your question: You want to move your "slider" under the link that is currently active or hovered. If this is what you want then I have a solution for you.

Since you didn't provide your CSS properties for the rest of the menu, I am using my own CSS properties to achieve this.

Instead of moving the "slider", I am using the padding-bottom property to move the slider. When you run this in your browser, it simulates as if it moved the "slider"

```
.menu li a.active,
.menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #E74C3C;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
```

}

Here is the complete solution in code snippet below. Do let me know if this isn't what you wanted and I will update my answer.

```css
.menu {
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.menu li:not(.slider) {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #2C3E50;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.menu li a.active,
.menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #E74C3C;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu .slider {
  height: 5px;
  width: calc(100% - 1rem);
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: #D6F1FF;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="/Home/Index">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="active" href="/Home/About">About</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/Account/Register">Register</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/Account/Login">Log in</a>
  </li>
  <li class="slider" id="menu_slider"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That was what I was looking for. Thanks! Sorry for not making it clear.

Comment: I have a problem when applying your code tho, the "slider" width extends over more than the options it should. I have added a print screen to the question.

Comment: I don't see the slider width going in the last picture you added. Could you highlight where exactly are you referring to?

Comment: Do you see the redline at the top of the button? That is the slider "width"

Comment: I see that but the slider isn't extending over the options but rather falling short from what I see. I don't know what your CSS code is for the rest of your menu items so I can't really do much without seeing your code. You could however, play around with the `width` of the `.menu .slider` to get the desired result.

Comment: The slider should only be on the selected button, not everybody else. In that sense it is much bigger than it should be. Following your example, when I hover contact, contact is the only one being red.

Comment: Was I mistaken when I thought width: calc(100% - 1rem); would calculate the length of the slider?

Comment: From what I understood in your original question, the `width` of the slider should be equal to the width of the menus. When you hover over a menu, that's when the `padding-bottom` property "moves" the slider under the hovered item. You can remove the `calc` from and simply use `width: 100%;` in your case.

It would be helpful if you created a jsFiddle with your version of code in order to fix the issue you're having.

Comment: I see, my bad. When I tried your example I only got a slider on the selected button. The "slider" I already had, I just need a method to make the slider start at the active button. When I press About, I would like the starting position of the slider to be "About" and not Home. I can create a sjFiddle, but maybe I should start a new question?

Comment: I think you can include the jsFiddle here since we're on the same issue.

Comment: Okei, I think the problem is within my css. When I use yours (https://jsfiddle.net/5zhjcqws/2/) with some modifications it works, so I guess I have to look for overlapping css in one of the css files.